# Using VBA, how to calculate a range of cells based on another cell range's value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of values that are either a negative value or a positive value and the ranges go from -360 to 3600, which is irrelevant.  I just want to populate ANOTHER cell based on that value using an If, Then statement.
I've done this in is Access and some ARcGIS programs but never tried it in Excel using VBA.

See my values:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Increase | Decrease | <Cell I want to populate with either decrease/increase based on value below
| 178%     | -43%     | <If this value is greater than 0, increase, If less than 0,Decrease
```

I've tried multiple variations of code I found on the web but Noting remotely even worked

Comment: Any reason you're looking for VBA? This is easily accomplished using an `IF` worksheet formula.

Comment: *using an If, Then statement.* Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Excel formula for that (assuming Increase should be written to A1):

`=IF(0<A2,"Increase",IF(A2<0,"Decrease","No change"))`

With VBA you can set it like this:

```
Public Sub Sub1()
    Dim textCell As Range: Set textCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Dim numberCell As Range: Set numberCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    If 0 < numberCell.Value Then
        textCell.Value = "Increase"
    ElseIf numberCell.Value < 0 Then
        textCell.Value = "Decrease"
    Else
        textCell.Value = "No change"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Is it only a joke or a test?  One answer given seems perfect : =IF(0<A2,"Increase",IF(A2<0,"Decrease","No change")), but your question is not clear. You have no reference about a calculation to do or a result to obtain.  If you want more help, try to be more focus!

I hope you will find some help in this forum.

Comment: I found help in this forum prior to your comment.  Apparently it was clear enough for another user to easily help me.  Thanks for stopping by!